# Is the derivative of the exponential family's density function absolute integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, density-function, exponential-family

Consider the [exponential family of distributions](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/exponential-family-of-distributions#:%7E:text=An%20exponential%20family%20is%20a,tractable%20from%20a%20mathematical%20viewpoint.), whose density can be written as:

$$f_\theta(x)=h(x)\exp\left[\eta(\theta)^T T(x)-A(\theta)\right]$$

where $h: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+$, $\theta$ is a $k \times 1$ vector of parameters, $\eta: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^L$ and $T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^L$.

Is the derivative $f^\prime_\theta(x)$ absolute integrable? That is, does the following integral always exists?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f^\prime_\theta(x)| dx$$

Any proof or counter-example is welcomed.

EDIT: one can assume both $h$ and $T$ are continuous and differentiable every where.

Comment: Is $h$ strictly positive, or is this a field where they write $\mathbb R^+$ to mean $\mathbb R^{\geq0}?$ In any event, if this is true for all $\theta,$ then it would have to be true for all $h$ and thus either for all distributions or all non-zero distributions.

Comment: $h$ is non-negative, as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)

Comment: In any even, it is not even obvious that $f_\theta$ is differentiable. Nothing says that $h$ is continuous, for example.